# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: php

Нужно достать значение id
Мой код:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Rysik5318", "password", "test");
$logged_user = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '".$_SESSION['logged_user']."' ");
echo $logged_user['id'];
```

Ошибка -
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in D:\OpenServer\domains\edrenbaton\index.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\OpenServer\domains\edrenbaton\index.php on line 19

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query` не извлекает данных, а лишь исполняет запрос. Он возвращает **объект** **[mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-result.php)**, у которого можно применять методы для извлечения данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но суть в том, что возвращается **объект**, а вы обращаетесь к нему как к массиву. Что неверно.

Для того, чтобы оперировать данными, как минимум надо пройти путь до `mysqli_result` и всяких `fetch_*`

Comment: Тоесть к коду надо добавить $rows = $logged_user->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); ?

Comment: Да. надо так.......и надо понимать, что $rows - это массив  и в цикле с ним работать https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-all-examples

Comment: Что-то по типу этого printf("(%s)", $rows["id"]); ?

Comment: я же пример дал выше)) если rowS - то `rows[0]['id']` / `rows[1]['id']` и т.д., если в цикле то `$row['id']`. использование printf - по желанию

Comment: Ничего не выводит, либо я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: ........ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ёклмн, я забыл указать $_SESSION['logged_user']->login